# Floating-point calculation C wrong result

Tags: c, floating-point, double

I am trying Jacobi iteration using double values. The following is the calculation snippet:

```
int current = 0, next = 1, k, temp;
for (k = 0; k < T; k++) {
    for (i = 1; i < N-1; i++)
        for (j = 1; j < N-1; j++)
            h[next][i][j] = 0.25 * (h[current][i-1][j] + h[current][i+1][j] +
                                    h[current][i][j-1] + h[current][i][j+1]);

    temp = current; // swap values of current and next
    current = next;
    next = temp;
}
```

All the initial values are between 20 and 100, so I am supposed to be getting answer between that range but I am getting a lot of values less than 20. Is there something about these floating-point values that I am missing?

Comment: If you're using C, don't tag with C++; you may get answers that are completely unusable in C — and vice versa.

Comment: Did you try debugging it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a 2x10x10 matrix, and loaded the first plane with 100 values in the range 20..100.  I printed it out.

```
 81.00 66.00 49.00 97.00 52.00 32.00 89.00 67.00 43.00 63.00
 32.00 25.00 73.00 91.00 34.00 90.00 87.00 96.00 41.00 72.00
 64.00 24.00 50.00 91.00 35.00 32.00 33.00 93.00 66.00 81.00
 51.00 37.00 59.00 60.00 30.00 50.00 90.00 91.00 60.00 31.00
 33.00 89.00 73.00 30.00 55.00 49.00 34.00 31.00 22.00 44.00
 77.00 24.00 49.00 40.00 97.00 40.00 53.00 77.00 47.00 36.00
 66.00 40.00 98.00 29.00 82.00 52.00 46.00 20.00 38.00 84.00
 47.00 83.00 21.00 98.00 51.00 26.00 33.00 77.00 81.00 91.00
 20.00 92.00 90.00 55.00 81.00 30.00 92.00 25.00 99.00 25.00
 20.00 95.00 22.00 46.00 38.00 29.00 89.00 96.00 71.00 95.00
```

I then ran the cycle once and printed out the new matrix.  The result was:

```
  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
  0.00 48.75 53.75 73.75 67.00 46.25 77.00 72.00 69.25  0.00
  0.00 44.00 61.75 59.00 46.75 52.00 75.50 71.50 68.75  0.00
  0.00 55.75 55.00 52.50 50.00 50.25 52.00 68.50 52.50  0.00
  0.00 41.75 56.75 57.00 51.50 44.75 55.75 56.00 45.50  0.00
  0.00 63.75 58.75 51.25 54.25 62.75 49.25 37.75 43.25  0.00
  0.00 67.75 34.75 79.50 57.25 48.50 39.50 59.50 58.00  0.00
  0.00 50.00 92.25 39.00 71.75 41.50 60.25 39.75 76.25  0.00
  0.00 72.00 47.50 78.75 43.50 57.00 44.25 91.00 50.50  0.00
  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00  0.00
```

Once those zeros round the edges are used in the averaging process, the values can fall below 20.  After the 10th iteration, the matrix was:

```
 81.00 66.00 49.00 97.00 52.00 32.00 89.00 67.00 43.00 63.00
 32.00 18.37 33.83 29.56 33.95 35.10 30.59 34.63 22.12 72.00
 64.00 30.39 39.09 46.96 44.80 43.59 46.86 43.94 29.90 81.00
 51.00 28.89 43.03 45.77 48.12 49.18 46.14 41.18 32.27 31.00
 33.00 32.54 43.42 46.96 51.67 48.78 48.37 43.41 28.15 44.00
 77.00 32.32 43.48 50.88 47.04 52.33 46.00 43.74 32.51 36.00
 66.00 28.82 47.41 40.65 51.60 44.21 48.91 43.45 33.35 84.00
 47.00 34.35 31.64 46.19 37.77 45.88 42.86 49.11 31.50 91.00
 20.00 13.57 32.95 22.67 31.39 30.35 34.15 31.62 25.91 25.00
 20.00 95.00 22.00 46.00 38.00 29.00 89.00 96.00 71.00 95.00
```

There is a value 18.37 and a value 13.57 in there.  So, you need to look to the borders of the `h[1]` plane of your matrix to decide what values should be in there.  The values around the border are not changed, but if they're zero to start with, they pull down the averages.

Comment: Thank you very much. I initialized h[next] same as h[current] and the problem was solved. I had spent like 15-20 hours on this.